# Using Spyder (Anaconda) environment to execute GRASS Python script in Windows 10

Tags: grass-gis, spyder

How can I set my spyder environment in order to use GRASS Python script in Spyder for Windows 10? I need to use some Python script from GRASS GIS. I am really new in Python and manipulate with scripts.
I follow the following setup to set my spyder environment but I always got error messages (No module named grass.script)

```
@echo off
rem set OSGEO4W_ROOT=c:\OSGEO4W64
rem set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%PATH%
call c:\osgeo4w64\bin\o4w_env.bat
call %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.6.0\etc\env.bat
set GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\gdalplugins\1.9
set PATH=%PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.6.0\lib
set PATH=%PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Scripts\
set GISBASE=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-7.6.0
set GISDBASE=C:\Users\Wael Hassan\Documents\grassdata
set GISRC=C:\Users\Wael Hassan\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7
set GRASS_SH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\msys\bin\sh.exe
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.6.0\etc\python
set QGISPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
start c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Scripts\spyder.bat
```

Comment: I try to use some python script from grass gis in spyder, but I could not set the environment properly can you help step by step how to do that!!

Comment: and also I don't have "spyder.bat" file

Comment: Here may be some info: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tools_for_Python_programming#Spyder_editor